# Variable isn't being set? ECHO is OFF

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

Now I'm attempting to make a program that will input something like:

```
dfe234
pfg156
lno678
```

(Psuedo) randomly using batch but unfortunately when I run:

```
@echo off

:generate
set /a digitone=%random% %% 6 + 1
set /a digittwo=%random% %% 6 + 1
set /a digitthr=%random% %% 6 + 1

set /a letters=(26 * %random%) / 32768 + 1 
for /f "tokens=%letters%" %%l in ("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z") do set letterone = %%l

set /a letters=(26 * %random%) / 32768 + 1 
for /f "tokens=%letters%" %%l in ("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z") do set lettertwo = %%l

set /a letters=(26 * %random%) / 32768 + 1 
for /f "tokens=%letters%" %%l in ("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z") do set letterthree = %%l

echo %letterone%%lettertwo%%letterthree%%digitone%%digittwo%%digitthr%
goto generate
```

I receive:

```
ECHO is OFF.
```

And a number, after a bit of tinkering I concluded that it wasn't setting the variables to `%%l`. Can someone help me and other with a similar problem? Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: set "var=value" - without the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Stephan is right, check http://ss64.com/nt/set.html section Variable names with spaces